# JAWS not reading updated input value

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am having a button and when updated that value using jQuery JAWS is not able to read the updated value. It still reads the old value.

```
<input id="save" type="button"  value= "Save" onClick="saveValues()" />

$("#save").attr('value', 'Update');
```

Value is getting changed to "Update" but JAWS still reads as "Save". How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Tried `$("#save").val('Update');`? It may be no different, but I cant remember how the `val()` setter works internally.

Comment: No.. Still JAWS reads as Save. I think it is not the problem with JQuery because i can see the updated value for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when i added the "title" attribute and updated the same using jquery

```
$('#save').attr('title', 'Update');
```